# Java how to put a button on border/surround of window or JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do I put a button on the border that surrounds the frame like this cog:

[image]

Comment: You can `setUndecorated(true)` on the frame and just implement your own at the top.

Comment: You either need to implement your own UI delegate or undecorated the window and implement your border

Comment: Is there a short example anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

> _"Is the a short example anywhere? "

Yea, here...  This very basic. You need to do alot more to it. You'll notice I have to add a `MouseMotionListener` to the `JPanel` that acts as the top frame border, because when you remove the decoration from the frame, you're also taking away that functionality. So the `MouseMotionListener` makes the frame draggable again.

You would also have to implement resizing if you wished. I already implemented the `System`exit()` when you press the image.  Test it out. You need to provide your own image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class UndecoratedExample {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static class MainPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    static class BorderPanel extends JPanel {

        JLabel stackLabel;
        int pX, pY;

        public BorderPanel() {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                    "/resources/stackoverflow1.png"));
            stackLabel = new JLabel();
            stackLabel.setIcon(icon);

            setBackground(Color.black);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

            add(stackLabel);

            stackLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                    // Get x,y and store them
                    pX = me.getX();
                    pY = me.getY();
                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                    frame.setLocation(frame.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX, 
                            frame.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    static class OutsidePanel extends JPanel {

        public OutsidePanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(new BorderPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.add(new OutsidePanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all that. But wow, what a lot of effort to add a button on a Frame. Is there definitely no simpler way?