# Swing JFrame : How to add a custom button to a jframe header

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

So far I got that we can remove the minimize/maximize etc buttons from a jframe (header).

[How can I remove just the Maximize button from a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625436/how-can-i-remove-just-the-maximize-button-from-a-jframe)

[How to hide the default minimize/maximize and close buttons on JFrame window in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101418/how-to-hide-the-default-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons-on-jframe-window-in)

Is there a way to add a custom button in a jframe(header)? I am trying to extend the default available jframe buttons feature and add my own "always on top" into it. If this is not possible then I would like to add some pinning icon into the jframe (header) to replicate "always on top" feature for a jframe (or jinternalframe).

This feature that I am trying to implement is similar to what we see on a linux machines with gui which enable us to keep a folder always in top.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6k76.jpg)

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215355/java-how-to-put-a-button-on-border-surround-of-window-or-jframe

Comment: @c0der Thanks for the link. It seems like we have to implement our own JFrame header. 
Well as of now I could not implement my "always on the top" option for the header, but have added keyboard shortcut to bring my target JInternelFrame to front whenever we need.

Comment: @c0der: I revisited this question after a long time. I can mark your comment as an answer but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your message. It is important to accept / up vote good answers. If you found the linked answer helpful please up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought, how about instead, you remove the JFrame header:

```
frameName.setUndecorated(true);
```

And simply create your own using a JPanel. With this method, you can fully customize a JFrame header!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not like the idea initially but now I know that this is the only way :). But as c0der pointed out this first, I want to select his comment as answer.